# Laravel Shopping Cart - Check if Session Array is Empty

Tags: php, laravel, session

I'm making an online shopping project with Laravel but there is a problem when I have not put anything into the cart, like this (before inserting and removing items from the cart):

[Example #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UE6oD.png)

**cart.blade.php:**

```
@if(!Session::has('cart'))
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 25px;width: 40%;">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <center>
                    <h4>Your shopping cart is empty :|</h4>
                    <a href="{{ route('index') }}">back to the homepage</a>
                </center>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@else
...........
@endif
```

After I add to the cart, then I remove the goods until the cart becomes empty.

[Example #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfdTD.png)

Like this (after inserting and removing items from cart, this table is not deleted):

[Example #3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgiWN.png)

Should be like this "your cart is empty."

**StoreController.php:**

```
<?php

........... ...
... .. . . ...
public function Cart()
{
    $interest = Products::OrderByRaw('RAND()')->take(2)->get();

    return view('shop.cart', compact('interest'));
}

..... .....
... .. ..
public function deleteCart($id)
{
    $cart = Session::get('cart');
    unset($cart[$id]);
    Session::put('cart', $cart);
    Session::flash('success', 'item has been removed.');

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

The array after the item is deleted use `dd($cart)`:

```
[]
```

Thanks for answering my question! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in whatever your blade file for rendering session cart data
you have to do some thing like this

```
@if(count($cart) > 0)
    <div> whatever your message is like shopping cart is empty </div>
@else
     //loop the session cart array and display it
     @foreach($c as $cart)
          <p> {{ $c }} </p>
     @endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, this problem has been solved by changing

`@if (! Session :: has ('cart'))`

TO

`@if (! Session :: has ('cart') || empty (Session :: get ('cart')))`

Answer (score 1):

this problem has been solved by changing

```
@if (! Session :: has ('cart'))
```

TO

```
@if (! Session :: has ('cart') || empty (Session :: get ('cart')))
```